# Wordpress core responsive video not working with shortcode

Tags: wordpress, video

I cannot get the video from Wordpress core to behave responsively.

I'm using the following CSS:

```
.videocontent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
} 

.wp-video-shortcode {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

The following HTML using the shortcode doesn't scale to the full size of the containing div:

```
<div class="videocontent">
    <?php
    echo do_shortcode('[video webm="http://localhost/dnp/stalker.webm" width=100%]');
    ?>
</div>
```

But using HTML directly it works fine:

```
<div class="videocontent">
    <video  id="myvideo2" style="width:90%;height:100%;" controls="controls">
      <source src="http://localhost/dnp/stalker.webm" type="video/webm"/>
    </video>
</div>
```

I have tried various settings with the shortcode - such as height 100%, height and width 100%, and width 100%.

What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot -> [screen shot](http://www.deekwa.com/screenshot.png)

Here's [an example of the above - try resizing browser](http://www.deekwa.com/dnp)

Comment: What's the HTML produced by the shortcode?

Comment: Have you tried using pixel values rather than percentages? I believe the arguments passed in the shortcode are used as used as width and height attributes on the video, no as style attributes.

Comment: <div class="mejs-mediaelement">
<video id="video-4-1" class="wp-video-shortcode" width="640" height="351" preload="metadata" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://localhost/dnp/stalker.webm">
</div>

Comment: Style HTML: <div style="width: 640px; max-width: 100%;">
<div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container svg wp-video-shortcode mejs-video" style="width: 640px; height: 351px;">

Comment: It's this class="mejs-containter" which is constraining the size to be 640px.....? If I delete that (in firebug) the video goes to the full width of the browser... Hmmm. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have a live link to the issue?

Comment: Sure - I will put one up. Gimme an hour.

Comment: Hi Jason : I just put the site up at http://www.deekwa.com/dnp/

Comment: I'm suppose that jQuery plugin fitVids can help you to handle that.

Comment: Possibly, but the WP Core uses mediaelement.js : So the WP Embedded Video *should* work...

Answer (score 9):

Use following css for WordPress video shortcode output

```
video{ width: 100%; height: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
.wp-video{width: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: The code works perfectly and makes video responsive.
Why is it not accepted as a correct answer?

Comment: I think you also need `.wp-video-shortcode{width: 100% !important}`

Comment: just using video{ width: 100%; height: 100%; max-width: 100%; } worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a theme and found that when I set max-width for video in the style sheet the WP-embedded video became unresponsive to changes in the browser width.

Comment: See this that just came in: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121410/wordpress-core-responsive-video-not-working-with-shortcode/121480?noredirect=1#121480

Answer (score 0):

When WordPress outputs the `[video]` shortcode it wraps the video in a DIV like:

```
<div style="width:640px;height:100px">
   video here ...
</div>
```

The width you're passing into the `[video]` shortcode can't be a percentage. So, you need to put a width formatted like `1030` for example.

```
<div class="videocontent">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[video webm="..." width="1030"]'); ?>
</div>
```

Currently you're taking a DIV and styling it to be responsive, but you're putting this *outside* of WordPress's output of the `[video]` shortcode. In looking at your example, if you scale the page down we can see that the your responsive video is indeed working. However, the problem is that it won't expand to more than 640px when the site is fully expanded.

So, I'm thinking you just need to make sure the original output of the video on the expanded site is big enough to fill your responsive wrapping div. Does this work?

*Note: I picked 1030 because that's how large your content area is on the example you're linking to.*

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Apparently the only way to get shortcode video and image to fit to different sized containers is by using content_width - a global variable. See the response I got from wordpress.stackexchange link on this page. Using the HTML5 code above it always fits the containing div. Makes using the embedded video feel very clunky having to set a glob var ... Maybe this will change.

Comment: Here's [an example of it not working - try resizing browser](http://www.deekwa.com/dnp) - however if you set $content_width=1000 before the shortcode call then the bottom video will behave as does the HTML5 code. Though the mediaelement.js really jerks when you resize the window on Firefox whereas the HTML5 is super smooth

Answer (score 0):

Your width parameter should be an integer instead of a percentage:

```
width="1140"
```

instead of

```
width=100%
```

according to the codex page on the [video shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode).

Comment: Is your desired width more than your theme's [$content_width](http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width)? That could cause it.